# Natural linewidth of hyperfine levels?

Tags: atomic-physics, laser, spectroscopy, cold-atoms, hyperfine-structure

The D<sub>2</sub> line of $^{87}\mathrm{Rb}$ is the transition between the $5^2\mathrm P_{3/2}$ and the $5^2\mathrm S_{1/2}$ states. Its linewidth $\Gamma$ is always quoted to be $\sim 6\ \mathrm{MHz}$.

But both states have hyperfine splittings.

The transition now is between each (allowed) pair of hyperfine states: **how do we calculate the linewidth of each of these transitions?**

Data sheet for rubidium-87 [here](http://steck.us/alkalidata/).

Comment: To my knowledge very few linewidths (or energy levels for that matter) in data sheets are calculated; they're typically taken directly from experiment. The question is therefore not particularly clear - what calculation are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I mean, each mF state in the manifold of Rb and K have the same linewidth. Why?

Comment: Apparently there is a theorem that justifies it.

Answer (score 1):

This is duplicate of the following:

- [Natural linewidth of hyperfine transitions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/324173/natural-linewidth-of-hyperfine-transitions)
- [Atomic natural line width](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209897/atomic-natural-line-width)

Is this answered sufficiently for you there?