# Natural linewidth of hyperfine transitions

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, spectroscopy, hyperfine-structure

I'm referring to this question: [Natural linewidth of hyperfine levels?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229339)

Let's take Rubidium-85 for example. It's written everywhere that the D2 line has a linewidth of around 6 MHz. But the D2 "line", a transition between fine structure levels, is basically just a composition of the underlying hyperfine lines, which are shifted in frequency by tens of MHz relative to the D2 line.

How can the D2 line have a linewidth of 6 MHz if the underlying hyperfine lines are shifted by way more than 6 MHz? My only explanation would be that the 6 MHz already refers to the hyperfine lines. But this would mean that they all have the same linewidth?

What's the truth here?

Comment: Yeah I'd still like to know the answer to that.

Answer (score 4):

Well, after asking some smart people and reading some papers, I can hopefully provide a satisfying explanation:

**All hyperfine sub-levels from a certain fine structure level share the same lifetime / linewidth to a certain accuracy.** 
They are not identical, but the differences are neglectable for most applications. Therefore, people say the D2 line has a linewidth of 6 MHz.

The rate of a certain dipole transitions is, to first order, determined by the dipole matrix element between the corresponding electronic total angular momentums $J$.
$$
\Gamma_{J\rightarrow J'} \propto \frac{\left<J|r|J'\right>}{2J'+1}
$$
The D2 line's hyperfine transitions share the same change in J, namely $3/2 \rightarrow 1/2$. The only difference between the hyperfine sub-levels with different $F$ from a certain fine structure level is the orientation of the electron spin (up or down), but nevertheless, they share the same $J$ and therefore the same rate / lifetime / linewidth.